# Why can I use Strings as keys in a HashMap?

Tags: java, hashmap

If two `String`s that are the same are not actually identical, then why can I use strings as keys in a `HashMap` without using the same `String` object?

```
String s1 = "Test";
String s2 = "Test";

System.out.println(s1 == s2); // should be false
System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // should be true

HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap();
map.put(s1, "foo");
System.out.println(map.get(s2)); // should be "foo"--but why?
```

Does `HashMap` have some special behavior for `String` objects? If not, why can two "different" strings be used to put and to get values from a hash?

Comment: Note that `s1 == s2` will be `true` because of string interning.

Comment: Then why is it standard practice to use `.equals()` for comparing `String`s?

Comment: @Ted Hopp s1 == s2 will be true because of *constant pooling*.

Comment: @TomMarthenal: Ted is talking about your specific case; that won't be true in general.

Comment: @Tom Because there may exist different String objects with the same value. Use one of the String constructors to force new objects being created. But in your example you are not using String constructors and it will print most likely true two times.

Comment: @EJP - According to the [JLS (§3.10.5)](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#19369): _"String literals-or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28)-are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method String.intern."_ Constant pooling is also in play, but string interning is the key mechanism to guarantee unique instances. Note that it would be the case that `s1 == s2` even if `s2` were initialized by, say, `s2 = "Te" + "st";`.

Comment: @Ted Hopp I agree, but I would call that constant pooling. String.intern() is a runtime API that the compiler doesn't have available to it. The documentation is guilty of over-simplification here.

Comment: @EJP - I don't know that it's an over-simplification. String literals (actually, all compile-time constant String expressions) are indeed interned. Somewhere the interning mechanism is being invoked for these values.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`HashMap` compares objects by calling `equals()` and `hashCode()`.
`String` overrides these methods to compare by value.

Answer (score 5):

In general, you can use String objects because HashMap uses `equals()` and not `==` to test for key equality.

Answer (score 4):

> If two Strings that are the same are not actually equal

But they are. They are equal under the equals() method, and that is the technique specified for equality testing in the `Map` interface.

```
System.out.println(s1 == s2); // should be false
```

But it isn't false! Both refer to the same string because of constant pooling by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

When the `HashMap` compares the key internally, it uses the `equals()` method, not `==`.  So object equality is fine for a key match, reference equality is not required if `equals()` is overridden (as in the case of `java.lang.String`.)

Answer (score 1):

> System.out.println(s1 == s2); // should be false

It should not. Java compiler may optimize and point two strings to the same location.

**Update**

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        String s1 = "abc";
        String s2 = "abc";

        System.out.println(s1 == s2);
    }

}
```

Output

```
javac Test.java
java Test
> true
```

Comment: Wrong, wrong, wrong.  You can easily prove it with simple code.

Comment: By "may optimize" I think you mean "must optimize," assuming the Java compiler is up to spec. http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/lexical.html#3.10.5

Comment: Wait - I misread the original. I called "new" for the two Strings.  My apologies.  I voted up again.  I was going too fast.

Answer (score -2):

we should really go back to the basic first.

computer science fundamental:

== compares memory address(reference)

.equals compares value stored in the memory address

java basic. there is only one copy of string object across entire jvm

Comment: Almost every line in your answer is subtly or blatantly wrong

Comment: These are not 'computer science fundamentals'. They are *Java* fundamentals. A Java reference is not necessarily a memory address. There can be multiple copies of a string if you use the `new String(...)` construction.